# Only when a post request fails should the Link stop

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Lobbies.json
`{"Lobbies":[]}`

jsonWorker.js

```
const fs = require('fs');

function lobbyUpdater(name, password) {
    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('Lobbies.json');
    let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
    // data.Lobbies.length = 0; // Remove this for production
    let newLobby = {"Name":name, "Password":password, "Players":1, "Mode":"", "Word":""}
    data.Lobbies.push(newLobby)
    fs.writeFile('Lobbies.json', JSON.stringify(data), 'utf8', function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
}

function lobbyAvailable(name) {
    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('Lobbies.json');
    let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
    for (let i = 0; i < data.Lobbies.length; i++) {
        if (data.Lobbies[i].Name.toUpperCase() === name.toUpperCase()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


module.exports = {
    lobbyUpdater,
    lobbyAvailable
};
```

post Request on index.js

```
app.post('/newLobby', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Lobby Name:", req.body.lobbyName);
  console.log("Lobby Password:", req.body.lobbyPassword);
  const jsonWorker = require('./jsonWorker');
  if (jsonWorker.lobbyAvailable(req.body.lobbyName)) {
    jsonWorker.lobbyUpdater(req.body.lobbyName, req.body.lobbyPassword);
  }
  else {
    res.sendStatus(403);
    console.log("Stopped A Lobby From Being Created");
  }
});
```

Code from react that is being followed
`<Link id="testLink" to="/Waiting-For-Players"><button id="submit" onClick={sendingRequest} className="WaitingForPlayers">Create Lobby</button></Link>`

sendingRequest function

```
function sendingRequest(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.post("http://localhost:4000/newLobby",
    {
        lobbyName: document.getElementById('lobbyName').value,
        lobbyPassword: document.getElementById('lobbyPassword').value
    },
    function (data, status) {
      console.log("Data", data);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log("Error received:", errorThrown);
      console.log("Stopping the post request.");
      return;
    })
    .then(function() {
      // Follow the Link component
      let linkToUse = document.getElementById("testLink");
      window.location.assign(linkToUse.to);
      console.log("Testing")
    });
}
```

My goal is to only have the Link be stopped if the post request throws a 403 forbidden since the lobby name would have already been in the json. The link should go through otherwise. I believe that the issue is that the .then function isn't going through as the console.log isn't showing up but I am really not sure why it isn't working. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Which log did you get after calling `sendingRequest`?

Comment: @NickVu If the function throws a 403 I get the error received and the stopping post request but if it succeeds, I don't get any log output